# How to communicate to the parent that child closed write end of the pipe?

Tags: linux, pipe, fork

`read` on a pipe returns 0 when the write end of the pipe has closed:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int pipefd[2];
    char c;

    pipe(pipefd);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    read(pipefd[0], &c, 1);
}
```

In the above code, `read` returns.  But this does not work if we fork a child:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int pipefd[2];
    char c;

    pipe(pipefd);

    if (fork())
        read(pipefd[0], &c, 1);
    else
        close(pipefd[1]);
}
```

Here, `close` succeeds, but `read` hangs.  What is the best way to communicate that the child has closed, so the parent's `read` will return (with 0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both parent and child have both read and write ends of the pipe. Because there is still an open write end, the read cannot return EOF.

The fix is the close the write end of the pipe if you're not planning to write into it, and close the read end of the pipe if you're not planning to read from it, e.g.

```
if (fork()) {
    close(pipefd[1]);
    read(pipefd[0], &c, 1);  /* == 0 */
} else {
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
}
```